# Right RAM for my laptop?

Tags: memory, fsb

I have a Sony Vaio with 2GB RAM DDR3, 1066 FSB.

I want to upgrade the RAM but I only have the DDR3 1333 FSB type. I put it in my laptop and it's working but somebody told me that it could dammage my laptop.

What happens if we put a high or low FSB ram but at the right voltage?

Comment: It will down clock to the lowest speed. So if you have 1066 RAM and add 1333 it will down clock the 1333 to 1066. It won't hurt your PC it's just hit or miss if it will work at that speed with the other RAM. Looks like you are lucky and it works... Also stock timings may be optimized for the speed so it may not preform as well as on a pc that supports 1333. Overall I doubt you will notice a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You would have known by now if it was going to damange your Laptop.

As it's already working that's fine, however it may just run at 1066 instead of the 1333 (as the ram slots may only support 1066).  It all comes down to what your motherboard can support.

However, it shouldn't cause any damange to your laptop.